# Java How to remove dates froma JTable that are after the specified date?

Tags: java, swing, date, simpledateformat

There are two dates. One in a table column and one by user input.
I like to display the date in table column that are after the user input date.

```
    for( int x = 0 ; x < defaulttablemodel.getRowCount() ; x ++ )
    if( ( date.after( new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yy" ).parse( 
    defaulttablemodel.getValueAt( x , 1 ).toString() ) ) ) )
    {

     defaulttablemodel.removeRow( x );

    }

   }

   catch( Exception exception )
   {}
```

The above code gives an idea about what the work is required.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your presentation.  Your code seems to answer the question in the title.  What is your question?  Creating a [mre] will help you and will help us help you.

Comment: Don’t swallow exception. An empty catch block is a no-no. You won’t discover what goes wrong in your program. It’s like coding blind-folded.

Comment: Maybe you need to implement a [row filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) ?

Comment: @ Abra No row sorter will only remove one particular row having specific string.

Answer (score 2):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [**ThreeTen-Backport**](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate1 = "23/11/20";
        String strDate2 = "20/12/20";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(strDate1, dtf);
        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(strDate2, dtf);

        if (date2.isAfter(date1)) {
            System.out.println(date2 + " is after " + date1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-20 is after 2020-11-23
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Assuming you correct `date` to be of type `LocalDate`, you should change your code to

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
for(int x = 0; x < defaulttablemodel.getRowCount(); x++) {
    if(date.isAfter(LocalDate.parse(defaulttablemodel.getValueAt(x, 1).toString()))) {
        defaulttablemodel.removeRow(x);
        //...Some code as per the requirement e.g. break; 
    }
    //...Some code as per the requirement 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But here problem is to remove row(s) containing date1 ( defaulttablemodel.getvalueat( x , 1 ) ). Is there any idea how to remove the roe containg date1.

Comment: @Snowrain - I've added an update. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @Snowrain - I hope the solution resolved your problem. If yes, you can help the community by marking the answer as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [row filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Note that the below code is merely a *proof of concept* (POC). Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class FltrTabl implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    private static final String  FILTER = "Filter";

    private JFrame  frame;
    private JSpinner  dateSpinner;
    private JTable  datesTable;
    private TableRowSorter<TablModl>  sorter;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object obj = dateSpinner.getValue();
        if (obj instanceof Date) {
            Date theDate = (Date) obj;
            LocalDate ld = Instant.ofEpochMilli(theDate.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            RowFilter<TablModl, Object> rf = RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, theDate);
            sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createFilterPanel() {
        JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Not after");
        filterPanel.add(label);
        SpinnerDateModel sdm = new SpinnerDateModel();
        dateSpinner = new JSpinner(sdm);
        filterPanel.add(dateSpinner);
        JButton filterButton = new JButton(FILTER);
        filterButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        filterButton.setToolTipText("Filter table.");
        filterButton.addActionListener(this);
        filterPanel.add(filterButton);
        return filterPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTable() {
        TablModl model = new TablModl();
        datesTable = new JTable(model);
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TablModl>(model);
        datesTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(datesTable);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createFilterPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createTable(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new FltrTabl());
    }
}

class TablModl extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final String[]  COLUMNS = new String[]{"Date"};

    Object[][]  data;

    public TablModl() {
        LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate lastDate = theDate.plusDays(100);
        data = new Object[101][1];
        int row = 0;
        while (!theDate.isAfter(lastDate)) {
            data[row++][0] = Date.from(theDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            theDate = theDate.plusDays(1);
        }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        if (column == 0) {
            return COLUMNS[0];
        }
        else {
            return super.getColumnName(column);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMNS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (rowIndex >= 0             &&
            rowIndex < getRowCount()  &&
            columnIndex >= 0          &&
            columnIndex < getColumnCount()) {
            return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `JTable` merely displays all the dates from the current date to 100 days in the future. The user enters a date using the `JSpinner`. Clicking the *Filter* `JButton` displays, in the `JTable`, only those dates that are earlier than, or equal to, the `JSpinner` value. Note that the code does no error checking, for example the user can enter any date he likes. If you enter a date that is before the current date, then the `JTable` will not display anything, i.e. it will be empty. Also note that I only use default formats for the dates. You can change the formats to suit your needs.